# SQL Server 2008 - How do i return a User-Defined Table Type from a Table-Valued Function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, user-defined-types

Here's my user-defined table type...

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[FooType] AS TABLE(
 [Bar] [INT],
)
```

This is what ive had to do in my table-valued function to return the type:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFoos]
RETURN @FooTypes TABLE ([Bar] [INT])
INSERT INTO @FooTypes (1)
RETURN
```

Basically, im having to re-declare my type definition in the RETURN statement of the function. Isnt there a way i can simply declare the type in the RETURN statement?

I would have thought this would work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetFoos]
RETURN @FooTypes [FooType]
INSERT INTO @FooTypes (1)
RETURN
```

Cannot find any help on MSDN/Google regarding this....anyone?

**EDIT**

I unmarked my answer, and bumping this question - as i am encountering the same scenario 6 months later.

Does anyone have any idea if it's possible to return a user defined table type from a table valued function? If not, is there a better workaround other than what i have done? (re-declare the type again).

Comment: Confirmed still not possible with 2014.

Comment: In SQL Server 2017, when the function is declared as `returns MyUDTT`, there is an intellisense error on the RETURN statement  at the bottom of the function, "RETURN statements in **scalar** valued functions must include an argument" [my emphasis] and you can't simply declare  the variable in the body of the function as a UDTT and get it to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok - so it cant be done.

Easy enough to duplicate the table definition in the return type (with the use of scripting).

Still - hopefully this issue gets rectified in the next version of SQL Server.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but IMVHO you should unmark your answer and mark the answer from James as it explains and solves the issue nicely.

Answer (score 62):

Even though you can not return the UDTT from a function, you can return a table variable and receive it in a UDTT **as long as the schema match**. The following code is tested in *SQL Server 2008 R2*

-- Create the UDTT

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyCustomUDDT AS TABLE
(
    FieldOne varchar (512),
    FieldTwo varchar(1024)
)
```

-- Declare your variables

```
DECLARE @uddt MyCustomUDDT;
DECLARE @Modifieduddt MyCustomUDDT;
```

// Call the function

```
INSERT INTO @Modifieduddt SELECT * FROM dbo.MyUDF(@uddt);
```

Function signature

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyUDF(@localUDDT MyCustomUDDT)
RETURNS @tableVar TABLE
(
    FieldOne varchar (512),
    FieldTwo varchar(1024)
)
AS
BEGIN
 --Modify your variable here
RETURN
END
```

Hopefully this will help somebody.

Comment: This is a better answer than the currently marked one.

Comment: ReadOnly must be mentioned when creating the function, like this `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyUDF(@localUDDT MyCustomUDDT READONLY)`

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran That probably is a requirement added by newer SQL Server versions. I believe, at the time of writing this (in 2014), the current solution worked fine in SQL 2008.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for [CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) indicates that the only way to define a table return type is by listing columns and types, a `<table_type_definition>`. Even [SQL Server "Denali"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx) has the same definition for `<table_type_definition>`. Although strangely, it's syntax doesn't include multi-statement Table valued functions, or anything else that references this fragment.

Comment: So i guess the answer is still no. :) Dang. All im trying to achieve here is a type of "contract" between the UDF and the code that is calling it. Keeps the T-SQL "D-R-Y". There's not much point even using the UDTT here if i can't return it from the function. Oh well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible. You cannot use a UDTT as the return type of a Scalar-Valued Function because it is not a scalar value. You also cannot replace the table declaration of a Table-Valued Function with a UDTT. Repeating the table definition seems to be the only option. If we knew why you were doing this, perhaps we could find an alternative.

Comment: I know i cant return a UDT from a Scalar function.

But in regards to Table functions - you are able to return tables (or table variables). A UDT is just another table so cant see why you cant return it. Oh well, maybe in the next version of SS. =)

Im doing this because i have a table variable which was being duplicated amongst numerous functions/procs. Therefore i put it in an UDT to prevent being "DRY". Easier to maintain, etc.

Comment: I can not believe this is still a limitation.  SQL Server 15 ...just ran a simple test. get "Invalid  syntax, expected Table.