# Passing a subquery directly to a table type parameter in USP in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's say I have an stored procedure defined with a table parameter and table parameter type

```
CREATE Type dbo.P1 AS TABLE 
(
    Id Int NOT NULL,
    Name nvarchar(50) NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_D]
(
    @id0 Int,
    @P1 dbo.P1 READONLY
)
AS
...
```

I can call this stored procedure by declaring a table variable

```
DECLARE @V as dbo.P1
```

Filling it with data

```
--tbl_V is just some table with data
INSERT INTO @V (id, name) SELECT id, name FROM tbl_V
```

and calling the stored procedure

```
Execute dbo.usp_d 
  @id0=1, -- some value
  @P1=@V
```

My question: is it possible to pass a query directly to the stored procedure in one step, without separate declaration of the `@P1` variable and inserting data into it, something like this:

```
Execute dbo.usp_d 
      @id0=1, -- some value
      @P1=(SELECT id, name FROM tbl_V)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the simple answer is, you can't.

`<Speculative Rant>`

This would have been an ideal opportunity for the SqlServer team to have used the [Table Valued Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) syntax, e.g.

```
Execute dbo.usp_d 
      @id0=1, -- some value
      @P1= VALUES(1, 'Hello');
```

(Albeit with some typing considerations).

Similarly, it is also [not possible to return a Table type from a Table Valued Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089553/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-return-a-user-defined-table-type-from-a-table-valued), which stymies the opportunity to at least do a Constructor TVF:

```
Execute dbo.usp_d 
      @id0=1, -- some value
      @P1= (SELECT * FROM dbo.ConstructorFunction(1, 'Hello'));
```

What would have been nice is Oracle-style nested table constructor syntax, e.g.

```
Execute dbo.usp_d 
      @id0=1, -- some value
      @P1= TABLE(dbo.P1(1, 'Hello'));
```

`</Speculative Rant>`