# How to use user defined table type in function for return?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

```
create type mt as table (a int, b int)
```

Below function works:

```
create function fn2()
returns @mt table (a int, b int)
as 
begin 
insert into @mt 
Select 1, 2 
return
end
```

**Below does not work:**

```
create function fn2()
returns @mt table mt
as 
begin 
insert into @mt 
Select 1, 2 
return
end
```

Any comments on how type 'mt' can be used for return type?

Comment: check this link for  why we can't use UDT as an return type in functions but you can find an alternatives or work around from this link  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089553/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-return-a-user-defined-table-type-from-a-table-valued

Comment: This is a [Connect Issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/675725) asking for this functionality, unfortunately it's been Closed and the "duplicate" it's linked to doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You [cant return UDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089553/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-return-a-user-defined-table-type-from-a-table-valued) from a function.UDTS are available as read only parameters to stored procs.

```
create function fn2()
returns @mt table (a int, b int)
as 
begin 
insert into @mt 
Select 1, 2 
return
end
```

This works because ,here you are returning table variable,The second cause doesn't work because you are trying to return table type which is not possible..

I don't see a need for using table type when you are able to accomplish same task .

You are using table type in a wrong way,the correct way to use it is like below in stored proc..

```
create type testtype as table
(
id int,
name varchar(100)
);
---stored proc which takes table as param

create proc tvp
@p testtype readonly
as
begin

set nocount on

select * from test1 t
join
@p p1
on p1.id=t.id

end

---now the way to call stored proc

---declare table variable as type of our table type and insert values

declare @p as testtype

insert @p
values
(1,'sateesh')

-----now call stored proc

exec dbo.tvp @p
```

Comment: No, I am talking about function and you are explaining me about procedure. 

My point is why return type user defined table type can't be used in function?

Comment: "UDTS are available as read only parameters to stored procs." this should read "UDTS are available as read only parameters to stored procs *[or functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471816/how-to-pass-user-defined-table-type-to-inline-function)*"

Answer (score 0):

:)

```
create function fn2()
returns table
as 
return (Select 1 a, 2 b)
```

Comment: No, this is not what I was expecting. I simplified my question to just highlight the point why return type as user defined table type can't be used in function?

Comment: It's not possible. There are some other way to use. Here you can find that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089553/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-return-a-user-defined-table-type-from-a-table-valued