# How to return MEMORY OPTIMIZED table from UDF?

Tags: sql-server, memory-optimized-tables

How to re-write the UDF returning table variable to the function returns memory-optimized type dbo.TypeOUT ?

```
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[test01]
GO
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[test01] (@id int)
    RETURNS @out table  (pid int,pname nvarchar(128))
AS
BEGIN
insert into @out(pid, pname) values(101, N'dobedo')
return;
END

CREATE TYPE dbo.TypeOUT AS TABLE  
(  
    id  int null,
    name nvarchar(128) null,
    RID    INT NOT  NULL  IDENTITY,  
    INDEX ix_RID HASH (RID) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT=1024)
   )   
   WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);  
GO

select * from dbo.test01(1)
```

Comment: I don't believe the answer has changed [since 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27159699/390122). But I'd be really happy for somebody to show me otherwise.

Comment: You are right, me too ;-)