# Cannot return a user table type form a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function, usertype

I just wrote this coe example to return a user type from a function:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ScheduledActivity_TVP AS TABLE 
(
    Id uniqueidentifier  NOT NULL primary key, 
    AdditionalDataTypeSignature nvarchar(100) not null, 
    AdditionalDataId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    AdmissionId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE  OR ALTER function [dbo].[Fun_GetFollowUpBymonth](@admissionId uniqueidentifier)      
            returns ScheduledActivity_TVP  as 
            begin
            declare @q ScheduledActivity_TVP
            insert into @q 
            select Id,
                   AdditionalDataTypeSignature,
                   AdditionalDataId,
                   AdmissionId 
            from ScheduledActivities
            where @admissionId = ScheduledActivities.AdmissionId;

            return @q
GO
```

And Sql Server tells me that I must declare the scalar variable `@q`.
What is wrong in the code above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2008 - How do i return a User-Defined Table Type from a Table-Valued Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089553/sql-server-2008-how-do-i-return-a-user-defined-table-type-from-a-table-valued)

Comment: So, the answers under the question that you gave told that it is impossible to use a UDT  as a return type in funciton(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are using a multi-line table value function here; they are notoriously slow.

Use an inline table value function, which doesn't even need a `TYPE`:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fun_GetFollowUpBymonth] (@admissionId uniqueidentifier)
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    SELECT Id,
           AdditionalDataTypeSignature,
           AdditionalDataId,
           AdmissionId
    FROM dbo.ScheduledActivities
    WHERE @admissionId = ScheduledActivities.AdmissionId;
```

Comment: Return of a user type value is a subtask of a bigger one. The main task is to cache values in query anywhere to use it in join expressions

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is, @frozen_synapse988 .